# How to Exit HardFault handler (cortex-m4) properly

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I am running on SOC using cortex-m4, when one of the HW components fail it raises bus-fault that cause Hard-Fault.

I want in the hard fault handler not only to print some registers and reset, I want instead to open UART connection to the device, the problem is that UART driver is using interrupts and I cannot open UART driver from Hard-Fault handler (cant call from within ISR)

Is there anyway to leave the hard-fault handler in a smart way (not including having the hard-fault raise a flag, then return and then the main() function will call the uart-driver) ?

Comment: i even tried to disable the bus fault but then i ended in "default handler"    `SCB->SHCSR ^= SCB_SHCSR_BUSFAULTENA_Msk; //Disable only BusFault_Handler
 SCB->CCR |= SCB_CCR_BFHFNMIGN_Msk; //Enable BFHFNMIGN`
'

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to the question, but a different solution to the problem: In situations like this I have actually written a second UART driver that is fully blocking that busy waits polling the appropriate registers.  The whole thing can be done in under a dozen lines.  Use this driver for the fault handling UART service.  The busy waiting is fine since you know you have only one possible context of operation remaining (unless you trigger NMI).

Comment: it is trivial to use the uart without interrupts (or even a driver).  just use it.